# Can route be used in two HTML pages AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

Something wired is happening in my code
So I have two Main HTML pages

```
index.html && adHome.html
```

They both use different routes but when I was trying to do this

```
angular
  .module('App', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngSanitize'

  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

   .when('/test', {
    templateUrl: 'views/user/main.html', //this is called in index.html
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })

  .when('/Reports', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/Reports.html', //this is called in adHome.html
    controller: 'reportController'
  })

 .otherwise({

    redirectTo: '/404' //used by both

  });

}
```

Now when I try to run the pages on my index.html everything seems to work fine but when I try to run something on my adHome.html I get this error

> Failed to instantiate module flowersApp due to: Error:
>   [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=n...)...

I think the issue is; that because adHome.html does not use these:

"'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngSanitize"

something happens and I get an error 
Because when I remove them, than everything seems to work on the adHome.html Page
but clearly I get errors in my index.html page because I am missing my injections

Could someone help me solve this?

Comment: you are injecting ngRoute twice

Comment: yea for some reason the second method just works but if I place them on the same injection and then try to call them in adHome.html I seem to get an error

Comment: you are missing a quote now on ngSanitize injection

Comment: Your question feels confusing, because you seem to be using both server side and client side routing at the same time.  You have an index.html page, which is it's own angular app, and addHome.html, which is *also* it's own angular app.  What you seem to be asking is how to share the `.config` block here between these two apps, when one of the two uses a large number of services and the other doesn't use any;  does this seem accurate?

Comment: Yes exactly adHome.html is an admin page so it's only called in for one user so why is it that the services prevent me from letting the pages share the .config block?

Answer (score 0):

You should fix with the following:

**app.js**:

```
var myApp = 
           angular
           .module('App', ['ngRoute']);
```

**route.provider.js:**

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
   .when('/test', {
    templateUrl: 'views/user/main.html', //this is called in index.html
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/Reports', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/Reports.html', //this is called in adHome.html
    controller: 'reportController'
  })
 .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/404' //used by both
  });
});
```

Or, you can avoid using `routeProvider` and use `stateProvider` instead.

**myRoute.route.js:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp')
        .config(myRoute);

    function myRoute($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('myRoute', {
                url: '/myUrl',
                parent: 'index',
                templateUrl: 'mySomething.html',
                controller: 'MyController',
                controllerAs: 'myCtrl'
            })
    }
})();
```

And using `$state.go('myRoute');` to browse your app while injecting `$state` in your components like `Controllers` or `Factories`.

I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: hey, Thanks for the answer but I changed the question a bit cause I think the problem was different